# Search for multiple values in IN clause located in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm extending search functionality and I need to add search for multiple values in IN clause. So I have textbox and write some number in it. This is dynamic functionality which could add query syntaxis to the `WHERE` clause of the sql and should be added only when you search.

Let's say we put 1056 in our textbox to search for it.

```
SELECT
   * 
FROM 
    QueryTable 
WHERE 
   (Select ID from SearchTable Where Number='1056') IN 
         (SELECT value FROM OPENJSON(JsonField,'$.Data.ArrayOfIds'))
```

This is working properly because searching for ID in `SearchTable` returns one row, but I want to make it work when returns multiple rows, something like this:

```
(Select ID from SearchTable Where Number like '%105%')
```

This obvious gives an error, because returns multiple records. **What is the approach to search multiple values(or array of values) in IN clause.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `EXISTS`. I *think* this is what you need (no sample data to test with to confirm):

```
FROM QueryTable QT
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM SearchTable ST
                   JOIN OPENJSON(QT.JsonField,'$.Data.ArrayOfIds') J ON ST.ID = J.[value]
              WHERE ST.Number LIKE '%105%')
```

*Note: I've added aliases to everything, but I've guessed the alias for `JsonField`. Quantifying your columns is really important to avoid unexpected behaviour and make your code easier to read for both yourself and others.*

Comment: This is smart, but OPENJSON(QT.JsonField,'$.Data.ArrayOfIds') returns array of number/Guids, so there is not J.[value] in it.It is something like [1,2,3,4]

Comment: That statement doesn't make any sense @mybirthname, as you state that your initial query works. If the `OPENJSON` query returns further JSON, then your query would not work either. So your comment above means that your statement *"This is working properly because searching for ID in SearchTable returns one row"* is untrue. Which is it?

Comment: Oh I'm stupid I didn't change ID to [value], it is working, my mistake to not change the value. I will accept after 3 minutes, thanks a lot !